# How to write multiple select query in mysql i.e one query is return some id's then i will write select query based on that return id's?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my requirment

i select users id based on email matching between two tables(a.b).then i will select infomation based on that users id in another table(c).

```
SELECT a.email, b.id
FROM `user_fnf_info` AS a
JOIN users AS b ON a.email = b.email
WHERE a.user_id =1;
```

it's possible in two queries in mysql,but i need to know how to write in a single query (mysql).

anyone help me on this requirement.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN` them with the third table:

```
SELECT a.email, b.id
FROM `user_fnf_info`     AS a
INNER JOIN users         AS b ON a.email   = b.email
INNER JOIN thethirdtable AS c ON a.user_id = c.user_id
WHERE a.user_id =1;
```

Comment: indeed but you should remove the AS to make it more database portable and why do you give the table users an alias "b" doesn't make sense and because off that the ON clause is harder to read.. And these aliases also pops up in the EXPLAIN statement so good luck optimizing if you have a large join or delivered tables...